# If condition not working properly [php,drupal]

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, imap

The following code should print 'It works!!', but it doesn't do so (it prints nothing), maybe it is related to encoding/decoding the value or $match array. I wonder where I went wrong. Please help!!

```
function my_module_init(){

  //$hostname,$username, $password are omitted here
   $inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password); 
   $header = array();
   $head = array();
   $MC = imap_check($inbox);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX
$result = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
foreach ($result as $overview){
    $hText = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $overview->uid, '0', FT_UID);
    $header = explode("\n", imap_fetchheader($inbox, $overview->uid, FT_UID)); 
    foreach($header as $k=>$v){
            if(preg_match('/^([^:]*):(.*)/',$v, $match)){
             $head[$overview->uid][$match[1]] = $match[2];

            }

}

}
//dsm($head[9690401]['X-Call-ID']); //prints "1074148121_43390920@64.158.162.74"
if($head[9690401]['X-Call-ID'] == "1074148121_43390920@64.158.162.74"){ 
    dsm('It works!!'); 
}

imap_close($inbox);

}
```

Comment: can you try var_dump($head[9690401]['X-Call-ID']) and share what that gives you?

Comment: @GratusD. it gives : string(35) " 1074148121_43390920@64.158.162.74 "

Comment: Could be you get into the function but your dsm is getting cleared and not output. What if you change that for a print and die;

Comment: @LeighMason , everything inside that if condition, doesnt work. I tried it

Comment: if you try the following is it getting into the if:

    $head[9690401]['X-Call-ID'] = "1074148121_43390920@64.158.162.74";
     if ($head[9690401]['X-Call-ID'] == "1074148121_43390920@64.158.162.74") {
    print 'in';die;
    }

If so then you know your data is getting messed up in your for loops. When did you do your dsm($head)? directly above your if statement or still within the for loop? As it could be your for loop is clearing out that array value

Comment: @seb_dom - am I seeing two white spaces at the beginning and end or was that something that just happened when typing it here?

Comment: @GratusD. ah yes I see it from var_dump, that's what it prints (with whitespaces)

Comment: @GratusD.  Thank you very much, I used trim() to remove whitespaces and it worked. if(trim($head[9690401]['X-Call-ID']) == "1074148121_43390920@64.158.162.74")